# Get a parameter from a URL and pass it to a href in WordPress

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I need to get 2 parameters in a URL. The URL will http://thisisurl.com?name=john&url=https://www.myrurl.com/
I need url=https://www.myrurl.com/ to be passed on to my href links on the page.
How can i do that?
Thanks

Comment: Hi, can you please explain more about what you need here? Do you mean you need an extra parameter in an <a> tag? Or are you trying to do something else?

Comment: Yes , in <a> tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create method `getParameterByName` to get parameter and use `.attr("href", url);` to update href of a tag

```js
function getParameterByName(name, url) {
    if (!url) url = window.location.href;
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, '\\$&');
    var regex = new RegExp('[?&]' + name + '(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)'),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
}
$(document).ready(function(){
var myurl = 'http://thisisurl.com?name=john&url=https://www.myrurl.com/'
var url = getParameterByName('url', myurl);
console.log(url);
$('.test').attr("href", url);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class='test'>Test</a>
```